# How to rebuild one single container and start all services with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker v20.10.18 and am trying to run two services through a `docker-compose.yml` file, one that is simply pulled from another registry, and another that I wish to rebuild quite regularly

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  inference:
      image: registry.example.com/image:latest
  main:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

When I need to rebuild the image my `main`, I do it via `docker compose build main`.

Then I can run both services with simply `docker compose up`.

I was wondering if there was a way to turn these two commands into a single one.

I have `docker compose up --build main`, but `main` is the only container that starts (after indeed being rebuilt)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that as a shell command:

```
docker compose build main && docker compose up
```

With the && you ensure that the 2nd command doesn't run if the 1st one fails. This is (not exactly, but similar to) how I do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command:
`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build main`

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/rebuild-docker-container-compose)

Comment: This only starts the `main` service for me